# How to skip carriage returns in csv file while reading from cloud storage using google cloud dataflow in java

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-data-api

I have a CSV file which consists of new carriage returns (\n) in each row.
While reading the CSV file from cloud storage using TextIO.read function of Apache beam it is considering  \n as new record. how can i overcome this issue.

I have tried with by extending filebasedsource but it is reading only first line of the CSV file when we apply pTransorms.

help will be appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by new carriage returns. Can you give a sample of your file?

Comment: Hi pablo, The one of  the cell in my CSV contains data like this "Identified 57 confirmed privileged accounts of these 32 are non-compliant to password policy
 This number is indicate" so it is taking "This number is indicate" as  next row. Due to parallel processing records after split are not adjacent too

Comment: HI Klutt, i tried with this TextIO.read().from("gs://***********") and even tried with             MySource source = new MySource("gs://*************", 2048,0,6);
   PCollection<TableRow> out=p.apply("ReadFileData", Read.from(source)).apply(ParDo.of(new RiskPercentageRowSplitter())); but both approaches are not helping in case of new line inside a cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextIO` can not do this - it always splits input based on carriage returns and is not aware of CSV-specific quoting of some of these carriage returns.

However, Beam 2.2 includes a transform that will make it very easy for you to write the CSV-specific (or any other file format specific reading) code yourself: `FileIO`. Do something like this:

```
p.apply(FileIO.match().filepattern("gs://..."))
 .apply(FileIO.readMatches())
 .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<ReadableFile, TableRow>() {
   @ProcessElement
   public void process(ProcessContext c) throws IOException {
     try (InputStream is = Channels.newInputStream(c.element().open())) {
       // ... Use your favorite Java CSV library ...
       ... c.output(next csv record) ...
     }
   }
 }))
```

Comment: Hi Jkff, Thanks for your reply. If we migrate from 2.1.0 to 2.2.0 how to set DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class); and how to set project id and which runner i need to set if i need to run locally

Comment: Same way as for 2.1.0, it's a backwards compatible release and all your existing code should keep working.

Comment: Hi jkff, Thanks. it is not able to read  : in filepattern Illegal char <:> at index 2: gs://bucketname/objectname

Comment: DataflowPipelineOptions is not able to read in 2.2 should i have both dependencies 2.1 and 2.2 in my pom.xml

Comment: hi jkff, i have added following dependency <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency> but after adding it is not able to detect DataFlowpipelineOptions and getting Illegal char <:> at index 2: gs://bucketname/objectname. please advice me on this

Comment: Could you file this as a separate question, and include your pom.xml and the relevant part of the source code and the complete error output?

Comment: Hi jkff,https://stackoverflow.com/q/47673002/7917789?sem=2 added new questiion for that