# Apache beam 2.2 dependency not able to get the data from cloud storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

This is my code to read csv

```
               //DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);    
                    PipelineOptions options=PipelineOptionsFactory.create();    
                        //options.setProject("ProjectId");
                        //options.setStagingLocation("gs://bucketname/Object");
                        options.setRunner(DirectRunner.class);
                        options.setTempLocation("gs://bucketname/Object");
                        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);          
                        p.apply(FileIO.match().filepattern("gs://bucketname/objectname.csv")).apply(FileIO.readMatches())
                        .apply(ParDo.of(new checkSplitter()));
                         p.run();       
                }
                static class checkSplitter extends DoFn<ReadableFile, String> {
                    /**
                     * 
                     */
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    int rown = 1;
                     String line;
                    @ProcessElement
                    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
                        try (InputStream is = Channels.newInputStream(c.element().open())) {
                            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                            while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                                System.out.println(line);
                            }
                             }

                    }
                }
```

My pom.xml:

```
         <dependency>
              <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
              <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
              <version>3.1.0</version>
              <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
             <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
          <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
          <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.0</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

            <!-- slf4j API frontend binding with JUL backend -->
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
              <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
              <version>1.7.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
              <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
              <version>1.7.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>google-api-services-pubsub</artifactId>
                    <version>v1-rev12-1.20.0</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
                            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-bigquery -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
                    <version>0.30.0-beta</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.5</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
                    <version>0.6</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.14</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.14</version>
                </dependency> -->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

The error is :

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: gs://bucketname/object.csv
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:344)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:314)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:208)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:62)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:303)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:289)
    at com.pearson.dataflow.StarterPipeline.main(StarterPipeline.java:107)
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: gs://bucketname/object.csv
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:176)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:147)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.LocalFileSystem.matchOne(LocalFileSystem.java:219)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.LocalFileSystem.match(LocalFileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match(FileSystems.java:125)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match(FileSystems.java:147)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match(FileSystems.java:159)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileIO$MatchAll$MatchFn.process(FileIO.java:341)
```

I have attached the the code and pom.xml with the error
so so many build in packages in 2.1 are not able to found in 2.2 please advice me or if there is any working example to run it in local please share me the link.

should i missed out any dependencies or any error in code please help me
help will be appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You said previously that you're upgrading from 2.1. Does exactly the same code compile (excluding the FileIO and ReadableFile bits) if you only change 2.2.0 to 2.1.0 in your pom.xml?

Comment: Yes, in addition to that i need to un comment DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);    instead of PipelineOptions options=PipelineOptionsFactory.create();  and i need to un comment these two lines also                        //options.setProject("ProjectId");
//options.setStagingLocation("gs://bucketname/Object"); and options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);

Comment: Hmm I'm looking at your pom.xml snippet and it seems like you're not declaring a dependency on the Dataflow runner, only on the Direct runner. You need to depend on beam-runners-dataflow-java also.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to run your pipeline actually on the direct runner, you probably need a dependency on beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform in order to communicate with Google Cloud filesystem.

Comment: with apache beam 2.1 we are not adding any dependencies for direct runner and dataflow  runner

Comment: after adding the dependencies in pom.xml  while running the program getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.createPrimitiveOutputInternal(Lorg/apache/beam/sdk/Pipeline;Lorg/apache/beam/sdk/values/WindowingStrategy;Lorg/apache/beam/sdk/values/PCollection$IsBounded;)Lorg/apache/beam/sdk/values/PCollection;

Comment: This is very strange and it clearly means that something is very wrong with the dependencies of your program but I'm not sure what. How are you invoking your program? Any chance that you're including only your program's .jar in the classpath but not including the dependencies?

Comment: From Eclipse IDE i am invoking as run as Dataflow pipeline, which tries to upload file google cloud storage and run the dataflow job but i am getting the above error.
project is working fine with apache beam 2.1 but the problem  was with carriage return when i go with 2.1

Comment: I have started new project with three dependencies beam-sdks-java-core:2.2,beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:2.0.0,beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java:2.0.0 and my code is

Comment: Ah this is the issue. These are all parts of the Beam SDK and they need to be kept at the same version.