# How to get the filename being processed when reading from GCS in Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is there anyway to get the filename being processed when reading from GCS using:

p.apply("Read from GCS", TextIO.read().from("gs://path/*")).

I need the filename in next ParDo for storing the output into the appropriate table.

this question is similar to [How to Get Filename when using file pattern match in google-cloud-dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983621/how-to-get-filename-when-using-file-pattern-match-in-google-cloud-dataflow) but last update was more than a year ago, so wondering if there is a new functionality that enables this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with `TextIO` per se, but Beam 2.2 includes transforms that allow you to do pretty much anything custom you want when reading files, using `FileIO.match()`, `FileIO.readMatches()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47669836/278042) . You'll need to use a `DoFn<ReadableFile, String>` that parses text files using regular Java facilities (as demonstrated in that answer) and also uses the `ReadableFile`'s `getMetadata()` to get the filename.

Comment: Hi, but in that case (reading file in custom DoFn using, f.e. InputStream) there will be no parallelism, no file splitting, am I correct?